Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0' provider is not registered on the local machine, and other errors
I would like to open an old Office 97 Access.mdb into a current one
Visual Studio 2022 64 Bits! project.
Office 365 is installed on the development computer.
but I can't open the Access database.
what's still wrong?
additionally I have
accessdatabaseengine_X64.exe /quiet
accessdatabaseengine.exe /quiet
installed.
My connection string is
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source=
I have tried some of the things in this article.
'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine
